# Symfony functional test - can't stay logged in

Tags: symfony, phpunit

After successfully using the crawler to log in I can't seem to stay authenticated. Once i'm authenticated I want to be able to run through each of my services and check the receive the correct response.

```
public function testGetClientsAction()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->followRedirects();

    $cookie = new Cookie('locale2', 'en', time() + 3600 * 24 * 7, '/', null, false, false);
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

    // Visit user login page and login
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('login')->form();
    $crawler = $client->submit($form, array('_username' => 'greg', '_password' => 'greg'));
    $client->insulate();

    $client->request(
       'GET', 
       '/clients/12345', 
        array(), 
        array(), 
        array('X-Requested-With' => "XMLHttpRequest")
    );

    print_r($client->getResponse()->getContent());
    die();

}
```

The print_r returns the page redirected to after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing `$client->followRedirects();`